# Using union and count(*) inside one select

Tags: sql, union

This is my attempt:

```
(select p.Id, p.Name, count(g.Day)
 from Points p, Game g
 where p.Id = g.Id
 group by p.Id, p.Name)
union
(select p.Id, p.Name, 0
 from Points p
 where p.Id not in 
 (select g1.Id from Game g1));
```

It doesn't work with count, only with sum. Why?

Comment: Working with `sum()`? There will be no difference. Also, I wonder what will be sense of `sum(g.Date)`. What do you mean "not working"?

Comment: There is a difference, because sum returns a table, using count doesn't. I want to count the rows per Id though.

Comment: Are you getting some error?

Comment: It says that both tables don't have the same schema.

Comment: I think you should typecast somehow the 0. Try to compare result type of the count() column for both queries. That could be DB specific

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I casted 0 to numeric ;)